# Would a notepad++ crash dump contain sensitive information?

Tags: notepad++, dump

I'm considering uploading a crash dump, but if it might contain the text of my documents, I'd rather not. Does it contain sensitive information? If so is there a way to separate it from useful stuff?

Comment: No, and therefore not needed.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know? What does it contain?

Comment: Open it and read it.

Comment: @JoeInternet not sure if you mean this, but also a good idea to search for sensitive words in the dump with a hex editor (although I do it in total commander lister; or with `strings` command + grep).

Answer (score 3):

Crash dumps don't contain document contents - generally they contain the full stack traces, error logs.

Comment: Feel free to verify for yourself by opening the .dmp in VS2010.

Comment: VS2010 was a helpful mention.

Comment: There are different kind of dumps AFAIK. I don't know about yours, but if you create a dump file with right click > `create dump` in `task manager`, of a process, it contains undo/redo history, unsaved documents, and even saved documents, for me. I don't know if any/which of these stuff is in other kind of dumps, but it is good to know this.